# C++ segmentation error when first parameter is null in comparison operator overload

Tags: c++, parameters, null, segmentation-fault, operator-keyword

I am writing a class called `Word`, that handles a c string and overloads the
`<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` operators.

**`word.h`:**

```
friend bool operator<(const Word &a, const Word &b);
```

**`word.cc`:**

```
bool operator<(const Word &a, const Word &b) {
  if(a == NULL && b == NULL)
    return false;

  if(a == NULL)
    return true;

  if(b == NULL)
    return false;

  return strcmp(a.wd, b.wd) < 0;  //wd is a valid c string, EDIT: changed to strcmp
}
```

**`main`:**

```
char* temp = NULL;     //EDIT: i was mistaken, temp is a char pointer
Word a("blah");    //a.wd = [b,l,a,h]
cout << (temp<a);
```

I get a segmentation error before the first line of the `operator<` method
after the last line in the `main`. I can correct the problem by writing

```
cout << (a>temp);
```

where the `operator>` is similarly defined and I get no errors but my
assignment requires `(temp < a)` to work so this is where I ask for help.

**EDIT:** I made a mistake the first time and i said temp was of type `Word`,
but it is actually of type `char*`. So I assume that the compiler converts
temp to a `Word` using one of my constructors. I dont know which one it would
use and why this would work since the first parameter is not `Word`.

here is the constructor I think is being used to make the `Word` using `temp`:

```
Word::Word(char* c, char* delimeters="\n") {
  char *temporary = "\0";
  if(c == NULL)
    c = temporary;
  check(stoppers!=NULL, "(Word(char*,char*))NULL pointer"); // exits the program if the expression is false
  if(strlen(c) == 0)
    size = DEFAULT_SIZE;  //10
  else
    size = strlen(c) + 1 + DEFAULT_SIZE;
  wd = new char[size];
  check(wd!=NULL, "Word(char*,char*))heap overflow");
  delimiters = new char[strlen(stoppers) + 1];      // EDIT: changed to []
  check(delimiters!=NULL,"Word(char*,char*))heap overflow");
  strcpy(wd,c);
  strcpy(delimiters,stoppers);
  count = strlen(wd);
}
```

`wd` is of type `char*`

thanks for looking at this big question and trying to help. let me know if you
need more code to look at

Comment: Please tag the question with the language you're using

Comment: We need to see some of the `Word` class. It isn't clear how comparison with `NULL` is implemented, or what the `wd` member is.

Comment: what does your debugger say? You can use its "trace into" or "step into" fucntion to see what the code is doing, step by step, including how/if it is converting a null `char*` into an object of `Word`.

Comment: @StarPilot i am using a very "primitive" editor.  i have to connect to my schools unix lab and so i have to use secure shell terminal and emacs to edit.  which im not sure but i dont think it has any debug functionality.  when i have some time later today ill copy paste this to a better editor and see what it says

Comment: You don't need to test references for NULL, by the language definition, a reference can't be NULL.

Comment: Simplify your life, use `std::string`.  It's been tested and verified, relieving you of these kinds of issues.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews looks like the professor provided `Word`, which would necessitate c-strings eventually. But yes, the NULL thing can go

Comment: Your Unix lab most probably has gdb debugger. gdb can be used directly from ssh. It's well worth learning.

Comment: @Arkadiy wow i didnt know ill look into it

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost positive you did not mean to construct a `char` on the heap with an initial value of some integer based on the size of `stoppers`:

```
delimiters = new char(strlen(stoppers) + 1); // Should use [] not ()
```

Also you are using C++ and I would never tell you what to do, but please, unless you know exactly that there is no danger, do not use `strcpy`. For exactly this reason.

It is a blind copy of strings, and when the destination does not have enough space (as is the case from your typo-ed allocation), things go BAD.

EDIT:

I also see in your overload of `operator<` that you use

```
a.wd < b.wd
```

and claim that .wds are valid C strings. If that is the case, you cannot apply a simple < operator to them and must use `strcmp`, `strncmp` or some other full compare function

Comment: oh wait, you mean to use [] instead of ()?  thats funny because that code was given to me by my college professor. lemme add it and see if it helps.
**EDIT:** nope i still get a segmentation error.

Comment: @user1774515 I am no professor and obviously don't know the context of this problem, but 99 times out of 100, that is not the idiom that was intended.

Comment: yeah that wasnt intended thanks for the tip.  also, yeah my professor stressed the dangers of strcpy.

Comment: @user1774515 I'd like to help more and will stare at the code a bit, but clearly it isn't the full source so I cannot reproduce the problem on my end and can only give you these tips :/ However, make note of my edit as well because currently you are just comparing pointers rather than the strings themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Cutting out the other bits of the constructor:

```
Word::Word(char* c, char* delimeters=NULL) {
    check(stoppers!=NULL, "(Word(char*,char*))NULL pointer");  //exits the program if the expression is false
    delimiters = new char[strlen(stoppers) + 1];
    check(delimiters!=NULL,"Word(char*,char*))heap overflow");
    strcpy(delimiters,stoppers);
}
```

You are allocating and copying to the input parameter (`delimiters`) not the member variable (`stoppers`). Therefore, when you call:

```
delimiters = new char[strlen(stoppers) + 1];
```

Here, `stoppers == NULL` (infered from the `check` call) so `strlen(NULL)` crashes.

Also, in:

```
bool operator<(const Word &a, const Word &b)
```

You check things like `a == NULL`. This is not needed as `a` and `b` are references, so the objects are non-null.

If `wd` can be null, you will need to change these to check `a.wd` and `b.wd`.

Comment: Hi there! I think from the comment on that line check(blah), it states that the program exits if the statement is *false*. Therefore, stoppers is != NULL after the check() call.

Comment: okay i set the default value to "\n" instead of NULL.  could you explain a bit more about how a cannot be NULL. should i do a* == NULL?

Comment: @user1774515 A reference cannot point to a NULL object so yes, *a would be an appropriate check (note the star before the variable, not after)